# Is it possible to concatenate a list of strings using only a single allocation?

Tags: c#, .net, concatenation, stringbuilder

After doing some profiling, we've discovered that the current way in which our app concatenates strings causes an enormous amount of memory churn and CPU time.

We're building a `List<string>` of strings to concatenate that is on the order of 500 thousand elements long, referencing several hundred megabytes worth of strings. We're trying to optimize this one small part of our app since it seems to account for a disproportionate amount of CPU and memory usage.

We do a lot of text processing :)

Theoretically, we should be able to perform the concatenation in a single allocation and N copies - we can know how many total characters are available in our string, so it should just be as simple as summing up the lengths of the component strings and allocating enough underlying memory to hold the result.

Assuming we're starting with a pre-filled `List<string>`, is it possible to concatenate all strings in that list using a single allocation?

Currently, we're using the `StringBuilder` class, but this stores its own intermediate buffer of all of the characters - so we have an ever growing chunk array, with each chunk storing a copy of the characters we're giving it. Far from ideal. The allocations for the array of chunks aren't horrible, but the worst part is that it allocates intermediate character arrays, which means N allocations and copies.

The best we can do right now is to call `List<string>.ToArray()` - which performs one copy of a 500k element array - and pass the resulting `string[]` to `string.Concat(params string[])`. `string.Concat()` then performs two allocations, one to copy the input array into an internal array, and the one to allocate the destination string's memory.

From referencesource.microsoft.com:

```
    public static String Concat(params String[] values) {
        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        // Spec#: Consider a postcondition saying the length of this string == the sum of each string in array
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        int totalLength=0;

        // -----------> Allocation #1 <---------
        String[] internalValues = new String[values.Length];
        
        for (int i=0; i<values.Length; i++) {
            string value = values[i];
            internalValues[i] = ((value==null)?(String.Empty):(value));
            totalLength += internalValues[i].Length;
            // check for overflow
            if (totalLength < 0) {
                throw new OutOfMemoryException();
            }
        }
        
        return ConcatArray(internalValues, totalLength);
    }

    private static String ConcatArray(String[] values, int totalLength) {

        // -----------------> Allocation #2 <---------------------
        String result =  FastAllocateString(totalLength);
        int currPos=0;

        for (int i=0; i<values.Length; i++) {
            Contract.Assert((currPos <= totalLength - values[i].Length), 
                            "[String.ConcatArray](currPos <= totalLength - values[i].Length)");

            FillStringChecked(result, currPos, values[i]);
            currPos+=values[i].Length;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Thus, in the best case, we have three allocations, two for arrays referencing the component strings, and one for the destination concatenated string.

Can we improve on this? Is it possible to concatenate a `List<string>` using a single allocation and a single loop of character copies?

## Edit 1

---

I'd like to summarize the various approaches discussed so far, and why they are still sub-optimal. I'd also like to set the parameters of the situation in concrete a little more, since I've received a lot of questions that try to side step the central question.

...

First, the structure of the code that I am working within. There are three layers:

- Layer one is a set of methods that produce my content. These methods return small-ish string objects, which I will call my 'component' strings'. These string objects will eventually be concatenated into a single string. I do not have the ability to modify these methods; I have to face the reality that they return string objects and move forward.
- Layer two is my code that calls these content producers and assembles the output, and is the subject of this question. I must call the content producer methods, collect the strings they return, and eventually concatenate the returned strings into a single string (reality is a little more complex; the returned strings are partitioned depending on how they're routed for output, and so I have several sets of large collections of strings).
- Layer three is a set of methods that accept a single large string for further processing. Changing the interface of that code is beyond my control.

Talking about some numbers: a typical batch run will collect ~500000 strings from the content producers, representing about 200-500 MB of memory. I need the most efficient way to concatenate these 500k strings into a single string.

...

Now I'd like to examine the approaches discussed so far. For the sake of numbers, assume we're running 64-bit, assume that we are collecting 500000 string objects, and assume that the aggregate size of the string objects totals 200 megabytes worth of character data. Also, assume that the original string object's memory is *not counted* toward any approach's total in the below analysis. I make this assumption because it is necessarily common to any and all approaches, because it is an assumption that we cannot change the interface of the content producers - they return 500k relatively small fully formed strings objects that I must then accept and somehow concatenate. As stated above, I cannot change this interface.

### Approach #1

*Content producers ----> `StringBuilder` ----> `string`*

Conceptually, this would be invoking the content producers, and directly writing the strings they return to a `StringBuilder`, and then later calling `StringBuilder.ToString()` to obtain the concatenated string.

By analyzing `StringBuilder`'s implementation, we can see that the cost of this boils down to 400 MB of allocations and copies:

- During the stage where we collect the output from the content producers, we're writing 200 MB of data to the `StringBuilder`. We would be performing one 200 MB allocation to pre-allocate the `StringBuilder`, and then 200 MB worth of copies as we copy and discard the strings returned from the content producers
- After we've collected all output from the content producers and have a fully formed `StringBuilder`, we then need to call `StringBuilder.ToString()`. This performs exactly one allocation (`string.FastAllocateString()`), and then copies the string data from its internal buffers to the string object's internal memory.

**Total cost: approximately 400 MB of allocations and copies**

### Approach #2

*Content producers ---> pre-allocated `char[]` ---> `string`*

This strategy is fairly simple. Assuming we know roughly how much character data we're going to be collecting from the producers, we can pre-allocate a `char[]` that is 200 MB large. Then, as we call the content producers, we copy the strings they return into our `char[]`. This accounts for 200 MB of allocations and copies. The final step to turn this into a string object is to pass it to the `new string(char[])` constructor. However, since strings are immutable and arrays are not, the constructor will make a copy of that entire array, causing it to allocate and copy another 200 MB of character data.

**Total cost: approximately 400 MB of allocations and copies**

### Approach #3:

*Content producers ---> `List<string>` ----> `string[]` ----> `string.Concat(string[])`*

- Pre-allocate a `List<string>` to be about 500k elements - approximately 4 MB of allocations for List's underlying array (500k * 8 bytes per pointer == 4 MB of memory).
- Call all of the content producers to collect their strings. Approximately 4 MB of copies, as we copy the pointer to the returned string into List's underlying array.
- Call `List<string>.ToArray()` to obtain a `string[]`. Approximately 4 MB of allocations and copies (again, we're really just copying pointers).
- Call `string.Concat(string[])`:

  - Concat will make a copy of the array provided to it before it does any real work. Approximately 4 MB of allocations and copies, again.
  - Concat will then allocate a single 'destination' string object using the internal `string.FastAllocateString()` special method. Approximately 200 MB of allocations.
  - Concat will then copy strings from its internal copy of the provided array directly into the destination. Approximately 200 MB of copies.

**Total cost: approximately 212 MB of allocations and copies**

---

None of these approaches are ideal, however approach #3 is very close. We're assuming that the absolute minimum of memory that needs to be allocated and copied is 200 MB (for the destination string), and here we get pretty close - 212 MB.

If there were a `string.Concat` overload that 1) Accepted an `IList<string>` and 2) did not make a copy of that IList before using it, then the problem would be solved. No such method is provided by .Net, hence the subject of this question.

## Edit 2

---

**Progress on a solution**.

I've done some testing with some hacked IL, and found that directly invoking `string.FastAllocateString(n)` (which is not usually invokable...) is about as fast as invoking `new string('\0', n)`, and both *seem* to allocate exactly as much memory as is expected.

From there, it seems its possible to acquire a pointer to the freshly allocated string using the `unsafe` and `fixed` statements.

And so, a rough solution begins to appear:

```
    private static string Concat( List<string> list )
    {
        int concatLength = 0;

        for( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
        {
            concatLength += list[i].Length;
        }

        string newString = new string( '\0', concatLength );

        unsafe
        {
            fixed( char* ptr = newString )
            {
                ...
            }
        }

        return newString;
    }
```

The next biggest hurdle is implementing or finding an efficient block copy method, ala Buffer.BlockCopy, except one that will accept `char*` types.

Comment: Do you know you can specify an initial capacity for stringbuilder in the ctor?

Comment: @blogbeard - That helps, but it still makes two copies - one copy for StringBuilder's internals, one copy when I convert that to a string. Or at least, that's what the reference source shows.

Comment: Ideally, you would not be using `List<string>` if you need the data in a different format. Why is it stored that way? Where is the data going (just to memory that must be in the form of a string)?

Comment: @JonathanWood - "Why is it stored that way?" Because we have a large text processing app that ultimately feeds very large strings to an external (native) library. Please focus on the question as asked.

Comment: It is possible to mutate strings using `unsafe` code, so you *could* create a string of the appropriate length then copy your source strings' characters into it.. but you would have to be very careful and sure of what you're doing.

Comment: If it were me I wouldn't store the strings in a List.  I would store everything in one string builder with new line breaks (or some unique delimiter).  And I would keep a list of indexes of the each strings start at 0 and after each delimiter.  Then I would copy out pieces of the string I need to concatenate into a 2nd string builder.  So you would only ever have 1 original string and 1 destination. Keeping in mind the 2gb object limit (can be surpased on .net 4.5).

Comment: @JonathanWood: I gave an answer saying the same thing as you are saying and it duly got down-voted. At times, we should focus on the solution for question and not question the question itself. From a systems design perspective you are so right, but with regards to this question you are going out of syllabus. :)

Comment: Also, how are you passing this string to your native library? You may be incurring another copy there.

Comment: In fact, if this string is just for passing to the native library, does it have to be a .Net string at all? You could just allocate some memory and copy bytes in from the `List<string>`?

Comment: @displayName: I tend to disagree. I have a background in C and assembler and do a lot of string handling in C#. This is the kind of issue I think I'm good at. But I have an issue with the setup. And 'm going to think outside the box to get a better handle on the constraints, and that means understanding those constraints. He doesn't want my help so I won't give it. But that's what I would need to help him.

Comment: @JonathanWood: I support your outside the box thinking. My first answer is an evidence of the same. Your disagreement is totally respected.

Comment: @jonathanwood - I appreciate your opinions, however the methods that produce my 'primitive' content return string objects, and that is not something I have control over. Sending those to a string builder will cause every one of those returned strings to be copied into the string builder and forgotten and then the string builder will perform copies to assemble the final output string. Too much copying of character data, nevermind the references to it.

Comment: @jonathanwood -The most efficient path, so far is to collect these component strings in a list, call ToArray, and pass the array of strings to string concat. I'd much rather duplicate a 4 meg array than the 200 megs worth of string data referenced by the array.

Comment: @JonathanWood - Please see my edits.

Comment: Seems like a lot of APIs that take variations of LPSTR can choke down a StringBuilder or even byte[] and don't even know it.  Maybe you can lie to your external API - tell it what it wants to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a method to concatenate a List into a single string that performs exactly one allocation.

The following code compiles under .Net 4.6 - `Block.MemoryCopy` wasn't added to .Net until 4.6.

The "unsafe" implementation:

```
public static unsafe class FastConcat
{
    public static string Concat( IList<string> list )
    {
        string destinationString;
        int destLengthChars = 0;

        for( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
        {
            destLengthChars += list[i].Length;
        }

        destinationString = new string( '\0', destLengthChars );

        unsafe
        {
            fixed( char* origDestPtr = destinationString )
            {
                char* destPtr = origDestPtr; // a pointer we can modify.
                string source;

                for( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
                {
                    source = list[i];

                    fixed( char* sourcePtr = source )
                    {
                        Buffer.MemoryCopy(
                            sourcePtr,
                            destPtr,
                            long.MaxValue,
                            source.Length * sizeof( char )
                        );
                    }

                    destPtr += source.Length;
                }
            }
        }

        return destinationString;
    }

}
```

The competing implementation is the following "safe" implementation:

```
public static string Concat( IList<string> list )
{
    return string.Concat( list.ToArray() )
}
```

---

**Memory consumption**

- The "unsafe" implementation performs exactly one allocation and zero temporary allocations. The `List<string>` is directly concatenated into a single, freshly allocated `string` object.
- The "safe" implementation requires two copies of the list - one, when I call `ToArray()` to pass it to string.Concat, and another when string.Concat performs its own internal copy of the array.

When concatenating a 500k element list, the "safe" string.Concat method allocates exactly 8 MB of extra memory in a 64-bit process, which I've confirmed by running the test driver in a memory monitor. This is what we would expect with the array copies performed by the safe implementation.

**CPU performance**

For small worksets, the unsafe implementation seems to win by about 25%.

The test driver was tested by compiling for 64-bit, installing the program into the native image cache via NGEN, and running from outside the debugger on an unloaded workstation.

From my test driver with a small workset (500k strings each 2-10 chars long):

```
Unsafe Time: 17.266 ms
Unsafe Time: 18.419 ms
Unsafe Time: 16.876 ms

Safe Time: 21.265 ms
Safe Time: 21.890 ms
Safe Time: 24.492 ms
```

Unsafe average: 17.520 ms. Safe average: 22.549 ms. Safe takes about 25% longer than unsafe. This is likely due to the extra work the safe implementation has to do, allocating temporary arrays.

...

From my test driver with a large workset (500k strings, each 500-800 chars long):

```
Unsafe Time: 498.122 ms
Unsafe Time: 513.725 ms
Unsafe Time: 515.016 ms

Safe Time: 487.456 ms
Safe Time: 499.508 ms
Safe Time: 512.390 ms
```

As you can see, the performance difference with large strings is roughly zero, likely because the time is dominated by the raw copy.

**Conclusion**

If you don't care about the array copies, the safe implementation is dead simple to implement, and is roughly as fast as the unsafe implementation. If you want to be absolutely perfect with memory usage, use the unsafe implementation.

---

I've attached the code I used for the test harness:

```
class PerfTestHarness
{
    private List<string> corpus;

    public PerfTestHarness( List<string> corpus )
    {
        this.corpus = corpus;

        // Warm up the JIT

        // Note that `result` is discarded. We reference it via 'result[0]' as an 
        // unused paramater to my prints to be absolutely sure it doesn't get 
        // optimized out. Cheap hack, but it works.
        string result;

        result = FastConcat.Concat( this.corpus );
        Console.WriteLine( "Fast warmup done", result[0] );

        result = string.Concat( this.corpus.ToArray() );
        Console.WriteLine( "Safe warmup done", result[0] );

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    public void PerfTestSafe()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        string result;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        watch.Start();
        result = string.Concat( this.corpus.ToArray() );
        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine( "Safe Time: {0:0.000} ms", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, result[0] );
        Console.WriteLine( "Memory usage: {0:0.000} MB", Environment.WorkingSet / 1000000.0 );
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void PerfTestUnsafe()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        string result;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        watch.Start();
        result = FastConcat.Concat( this.corpus );
        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine( "Unsafe Time: {0:0.000} ms", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, result[0] );
        Console.WriteLine( "Memory usage: {0:0.000} MB", Environment.WorkingSet / 1000000.0 );
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can determine the length of the concatenation before trying to perform the operation, a char array can beat string builder in some use cases. Manipulating the characters within the array prevents the multiple allocations.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cisg/archive/2008/09/09/performance-analysis-reveals-char-array-is-better-than-stringbuilder.aspx

**UPDATE**

Please check out this internal implementation of the `String.Join` from .NET - it uses unsafe code with pointers to avoid multiple allocations. Unless I'm missing something, it would seem you can re-write this using your List to accomplish what you want:

```
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated 
    public unsafe static String Join(String separator, String[] value, int startIndex, int count) {
        //Range check the array 
        if (value == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        if (startIndex < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_StartIndex"));
        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NegativeCount")); 

        if (startIndex > value.Length - count) 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_IndexCountBuffer")); 
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        //Treat null as empty string.
        if (separator == null) {
            separator = String.Empty;
        } 

        //If count is 0, that skews a whole bunch of the calculations below, so just special case that. 
        if (count == 0) { 
            return String.Empty;
        } 

        int jointLength = 0;
        //Figure out the total length of the strings in value
        int endIndex = startIndex + count - 1; 
        for (int stringToJoinIndex = startIndex; stringToJoinIndex <= endIndex; stringToJoinIndex++) {
            if (value[stringToJoinIndex] != null) { 
                jointLength += value[stringToJoinIndex].Length; 
            }
        } 

        //Add enough room for the separator.
        jointLength += (count - 1) * separator.Length;

        // Note that we may not catch all overflows with this check (since we could have wrapped around the 4gb range any number of times
        // and landed back in the positive range.) The input array might be modifed from other threads, 
        // so we have to do an overflow check before each append below anyway. Those overflows will get caught down there. 
        if ((jointLength < 0) || ((jointLength + 1) < 0) ) {
            throw new OutOfMemoryException(); 
        }

        //If this is an empty string, just return.
        if (jointLength == 0) { 
            return String.Empty;
        } 

        string jointString = FastAllocateString( jointLength );
        fixed (char * pointerToJointString = &jointString.m_firstChar) { 
            UnSafeCharBuffer charBuffer = new UnSafeCharBuffer( pointerToJointString, jointLength);

            // Append the first string first and then append each following string prefixed by the separator.
            charBuffer.AppendString( value[startIndex] ); 
            for (int stringToJoinIndex = startIndex + 1; stringToJoinIndex <= endIndex; stringToJoinIndex++) {
                charBuffer.AppendString( separator ); 
                charBuffer.AppendString( value[stringToJoinIndex] ); 
            }
            Contract.Assert(*(pointerToJointString + charBuffer.Length) == '\0', "String must be null-terminated!"); 
        }

        return jointString;
    }
```

Source: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/String@cs/1305376/String@cs

**UPDATE 2**

Good point on the fast allocate. According to an old SO post, you can wrap FastAllocate using reflection (assuming of course you'd cache the fastAllocate method reference so you just called `Invoke` each time. Perhaps the tradeoff of the call is better than what you're doing now.

```
var fastAllocate = typeof (string).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .First(x => x.Name == "FastAllocateString");
var newString = (string)fastAllocate.Invoke(null, new object[] {20});
Console.WriteLine(newString.Length); // 20
```

Perhaps another approach is to use unsafe code to copy your allocation into a char* array, then pass this to the string constructor. The string constructor with char* is an `extern` passed to the underlying C++ implementation. I haven't found a reliable source for that code to confirm, but perhaps this can be faster for you. The non-prod ready code (no checks for potential overflow, add fixed to lock strings from garbage collection, etc) would start with:

```
    public unsafe string MyConcat(List<string> values)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int totalLength = values.Sum(m => m.Length);
        char* concat = stackalloc char[totalLength + 1]; // Add additional char for null term
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            foreach (var c in value)
            {
                concat[index] = c;
                index++;
            }
        }
        concat[index] = '\0';
        return new string(concat);
    }
```

Now I'm all out of ideas for this :) Perhaps somebody can figure out a method here with marshalling to avoid unsafe code. Since introducing unsafe code requires adding the unsafe flag to compilation, consider adding this piece as a separate dll to minimize your app's security risk if you go down that route.

Comment: This method allocates twice as much memory as is ideally required - one, when I construct my own `char[]`, and two, when the `string(char[])` constructor makes a full copy of that `char[]`. If I have a list referencing 200 MB worth of strings, with this method I will allocate 400 MB. Unfortunately, this won't suffice. We'd be better off with `List<string>.ToArray()`, since the array's memory itself is 'only' 500k elements long, roughly 500k * 8 = 4 megabytes extra.

Comment: You may not get a win with CPU and memory usage - may have to trade 1 for the other based on your server capabilities. This could be better in the CPU area. I don't know of a better approach on the memory side. Also, because unlike stringbuilder it's not internally resizing, wouldn't that also improve your performance (even with large initial capacity of stringbuilder)?

Comment: I added the source for String.Join - seems that would be better for you if you adapted this to use your List<string> input directly instead of the string array.

Comment: Can't use that code - no access to `FastAllocateString()`, which is sort of the crux of the problem - .Net provides no manner to directly allocate and construct string objects (it does so on purpose, do my detriment). I'm looking for an unconventional solution or an answer that no solution exists.

Comment: @antiduh: I wish `String.Join` had provided a means of concatenating a known-size quantity of data supplied via callback method.  Since the callback method would never get any access to the string under construction, such a Join implementation could support "stringbuilder-like" semantics but it wouldn't need any extra allocations in the case where the total string length was correctly predicted.

Comment: @supercat - yeah, I completely agree. I think the problem is that just about any implementation that performs real string initialization has to be guarded against the input data changing (say, from another thread) while performing the concatenation. I think.. if that guarding (duplicate allocations) weren't there, it would be possible to cause memory corruption by modifying, say, my string[] on another thread while string.Concat copies its values into the destination string's memory - you'd be able to cause buffer overflows, if you replaced one string in the array with a much longer one.

Comment: @JasonW - Yeah, FastAllocate has been what I've been eyeing. I saw the code you pasted before, which gets us halfway there - the allocation. Next we have to figure out how to actually write to the under-the-hood string array - that is, obtain a pointer to string.m_firstChar ala `fixed (char* = &someString.m_firstChar)`

Comment: @JasonW - About the `char*` approach, the `new string(char*)` constructor performs a deep copy of the provided data, meaning we're back in the ~400 MB territory again. You can test this by constructing such a `char*`, sending it to the string constructor, modifying your `char*`, and observing that your previously constructed string does not reflect the modifications. Flergl. Also geez man are you sure you want to allocate 200 MB on the stack? That's a lot of memory, and it's going to be reclaimed as soon as I return from the method :)

Comment: I was just throwing out ideas..you're right. At least you got a little further down the road :)

Comment: @antiduh: It would be possible to write a safe `String.Concat` method without it having to copy the source array if it were to fetch the length of each item immediately before before each concatentation and ensure that it will fit.  If an item doesn't fit, construct a `string[]` containing all remaining strings, total their length with the partially-built string, and then join them all together.  If at the end of the concatenation process the string doesn't use its entire length, shrink it if possible, or else make a proper-length copy.  Extra allocations would thus only be needed if the...

Comment: ...`String[]` was altered during the concatenation operation, and both safety and correctness would be maintained even then [the concatenation would yield a combination of strings which each element of the `String[]` had contained at some point during the call].

Comment: @JasonW - check out my edits. `new string('\0', n)` seems to be the trick to allocating, and then the unsafe/fixed stuff you pointed to gets us a writable pointer. Just need to implement a fast block copy and it's done.

Comment: @supercat - "It would be possible to write a safe String.Concat method without it having to copy the source array if it were to fetch the length of each item immediately before before each concatentation and ensure that it will fit." That is exactly my thesis, however actually providing an implementation, since allocating and writing your own string objects is not immediately possible, is the entire crux of this question.

Comment: @antiduh: I was responding to the idea that the possibility of input references (or the lengths of strings identified thereby) changing during a copy would make it difficult to have a safe "Concat" method without having an array of all the strings.

Comment: @JasonW - I've posted an answer with an implementation, if you're curious.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the average length of the strings is very small, the most efficient approach, given a `List<String>`, will be to use `ToArray()` to copy it to a new `String[]`, and pass that to a concatenation or joining method.  Doing that may cause a wasted allocation for an array of references if the concatenation or joining method wants to make a copy of its array before it starts, but that would only allocate one reference per string, there will only be one allocation to hold character data, and it will be correctly sized to hold the entire string.

If you're building the data structure yourself, you might gain a little bit of efficiency by initializing a `String[]` to the estimated required size, populating it yourself, and expanding it as needed.  That would save one allocation of a `String[]` worth of data.

Another approach would be to allocate a `String[8192][]` and then allocate a `String[8192]` for each array of strings as you go along.  Once you're all done, you'll know exactly what size `String[]` you need to pass to the `Concat` method so you can create an array of that exact size.  This approach would require a greater quantity of allocations, but only the final `String[]` and the `String` itself would need to go on the Large Object Heap.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shame the constraints you're putting on yourself.  It's very blockily structured, and it's hard to get any flow going.  For example, if you didn't expect a IList but only expected IEnumerable you might be able to make it easier for the *producer* of your content.  Not only that, you could make your processing benefit from being able to consume the strings only as you need them - and only as they're produced.

This gets you on down the road to some nice asynchrony.

One the other end, they're making you send to whole thing at once.  That's tough.

But having said that, and since you're going to run it over and over, etc... I'm wondering if you couldn't create your string buffer or byte buffer or StringBuilder or whatever - and reuse it between executions -   allocate the max monster (or progressively bump-reallocate it as needed) one time - and don't let the gc have it.  The string constructor will copy it over and over again - but that's a single allocation per cycle.  If you're running this so much you're making the machine hot, then it might be worth the hit.  I've made precisely that tradeoff in the near past (but I didn't have 5gb to choke on).   It felt dirty at first - but ooohh - the throughput spoke loudly!

Also, it may be possible, that while your native API expects a string, but you can lie to it - let it think you're giving it a string.  You can very probably pass the buffer with a null char at the end - or with the length - depending on the API's particulars.  I think one or two commenters spoke to this.  In such a case, you may probably need your buffer pinned for the duration of the calls to the native consumer of your big ol' string.

If this is the case, you're down to a one-time allocation of a buffer, repeated copies into it, and that's it.  It could go way under your proposed best case.

Comment: C'mon man... The title of the post is "Is it possible to concatenate a list of strings using only a single allocation?". That's the problem I want to solve, and I've made that pretty clear. It's theoretically possible, so lets make it practically possible, even if it requires some hard thinking and a little bit of magic. I don't have the possibility of restructuring the parts around it, they are not parts I own. I get strings, I concatenate strings, I send strings.

Comment: Yeah, I know - I risk a downvote suggesting stuff that's not "the answer", but I've seen plenty of SO questions where the right answer isn't the answer to the question.  Since you've give so much background, it seems that an off-in-another-direction answer might at least prompt some thinking.  Generally, some out-of-the-box is appreciated - but I get it if you don't like it.  No offense meant.  For all I know you've considered all this before - but just in case - and maybe somebody else will come along with the same problem (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

The first two of my answers have now been already incorporated in the question. Here is my highly situation dependent, but useful -

### **Third Answer**

If in all these MBs of string you are getting a lot of strings that are same, then a smarter way would be use two dictionaries, one would be `Dictionary<int, int>` to store `position` and "Id" of the string at that position while another would be a `Dictionary<int, int>` to store the "Id" and the index of actual string in the original string[].

Coincidentally for me, *what I am trying to do is already implemented in C#*. Goes kinda like this...

If indeed there are a lot of same strings, is it a rare case where [String Interning](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-stringintern-m.html) is useful? You are guaranteed to save considerable amount of your **200 MB** target if a lot of matching strings are coming from the content producers.

**What is String.Intern?**

> When you use strings in C#, the CLR does something clever called
>   string interning. It's a way of storing one copy of any string. If you
>   end up having a hundred—or, worse, a million—strings with the same
>   value, it's a waste to take up all of that memory storing the same
>   string over and over again. String  interning is a way around that.
>   The CLR maintains a table called the intern pool that contains a
>   single, unique reference to every literal string that's either
>   declared or created programmatically while your program's running. And
>   the .NET Framework gives you two useful methods for interacting with
>   the intern pool: String.Intern() and String.IsInterned().
>
> The way String.Intern() works is pretty straightforward. You pass it a
>   single string as an argument. If that string is already in the intern
>   pool, it returns a reference to that string. If it's not already in
>   the intern pool, it adds it and returns the same reference you passed
>   into it.

The way to use String Interning is explained in the link. For the sake of completeness of this answer I can add the code here but only if you feel that these solutions are useful.

Comment: -1 didn't read the question. I'm aware of how to use a StringBuilder; having the invoking code collect its strings in a StringBuilder is sidestepping the question. The question: We start with a `List<string>`. Is it possible to turn that into a `string` in a single allocation?

Comment: Please see my edits for an analysis of your strategy.

Comment: Additionally, `string.Join(string, IEnumerable<string>)` uses a `StringBuilder` under the hood, putting it in the 'double-allocate-and-copy' bucket. It's actually much worse than that because its going to using a StringBuilder that's going to need to grow many many times. It has to use a StringBuilder, and it has to use it in this manner because by passing the list as an IEnumerable, I've lost information - how many elements there are, and direct access to each element as I please.

Comment: I don't think string interning is the way to go here, especially since this system has data constantly flowing through it (one batch after the other). I'd also doubt that the interning pool would willingly store many hundreds of megabytes of string data. Furthermore, all interning does is cache string objects - in many of the techniques discussed here, the identity of a string object is not preserved - copies to character buffers, etc.

Comment: @antiduh: The strings will stay alive and therefore cached as long as you haven't returned their concatenation. Pool definitely will store the data, no matter how many hundreds of MB as long as the code doesn't crash.

Comment: @antiduh: You can preserve the identity by adding a check at the receiving of every string from the content producers - `if(String.IsInterned(value) != null) {just make a reference} else {create new}`.

Comment: @antiduh: The drawback is only when the strings are all different or at least a high percentage of them is different. In that case interning is no better than your 3rd approach.

Answer (score 0):

[StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1h0a5sy(v=vs.100).aspx) was designed to concatenate strings efficiently. It has no other purpose.
Use the constructor which sets the initial capacity:

```
  int totalLength = CalcTotalLength();

  // sufficient capacity 
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(totalLength);
```

But then you say that even StringBuilder allocates intermediate memory, and you want to do better...

These are unusual requirements, so you need to write a function which suits your situation (creating a char[] of appropriate size, then filling it in). I'm sure you are more than capable.

Comment: And how do you turn that `char[]` into a `string` object? `new string(char[])` performs a copy of the provided array, which in my case, is a copy of 200 MB of memory.

Comment: Copying 200 MB is not the end of the world. But suppose it is... then you really need a different programming language (e.g. C++) or an upgraded PC.

Comment: "Copying 200MB.." That is literally the entire point of this post. I'm working on a large content production system that produces a huge amount of text output, and we're batch processing very large chunks of text. I'm not copying 200 MB once, I'm copying it again, and again, and again. Your answer and comments add nothing to the conversation.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. Or maybe I told you the solution... C++

Comment: Changing the language of the implementation is not acceptable.