# Apply Trim() to string without assignment to variable

Tags: c#, trim

Is it possible to apply a `Trim()` to a string without assignment to a new or existing variable?

```
var myString = "  my string  ";
myString.Trim();

// myString is now value "my string"
```

Instead of having to assign it to a new variable or itself?

```
var myString = "  my string  ";
myString = myString.Trim();

// myString is now value "my string"
```

Comment: No. Strings are immutable. `StringBuilder` is the mutable variant.

Comment: You need the just show the trimmed string in the result without assignment to the variable ?

Comment: Thanks guys!  It seemed like a silly question, but I wondered why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's not possible (within the use of the language).

The `String` class in .NET is immutable, which means that a specific string never will change. This allows for the code to pass strings around between methods without having to copy the strings to keep the original from changing.

---

The string is stored somewhere in memory, so if you go digging after it you could change the contents of the object and thereby change the value of the string. This however violates the rules for how strings work in the language, and you may end up changing a string that is used somewhere that you didn't anticipate.

String literals are interned by the compiler, which means that even if you have `"  my string  "` written in several places in the code, it will only be one string object when compiled. If you would change that string, you would change it for all places where it is used.

Example:

```
string test = "My string";

unsafe {
  // Note: example of what NOT TO DO!
  fixed (char* p = test) {
    *p = 'X';
  }
}

string another = "My string";
Console.WriteLine(another);
```

Output:

```
Xy string
```

Comment: Learned something new on the unsafe example +1

Answer (score 4):

To formalize the comments, strings are immutable and cannot be changed in-line as you are wanting to do.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The value of the String object is the content of the sequential collection, and that value is immutable (that is, it is read-only).

It goes on to discuss the immutability in more depth:

> A String object is called immutable (read-only), because its value cannot be modified after it has been created. Methods that appear to modify a String object actually return a new String object that contains the modification.

Therefore, you cannot write a method (even as an extension since `this` and `ref` cannot be used together) that would cause the underlying string to physically be trimmed and return in the same line. You must assign the new value.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate answer is, no, that once you have a string object, it cannot be changed. If you need a string that is missing those spaces, you have no option but to let the .Net library and/or VM allocate another string for you that's been trimmed.

If that allocation is unacceptable for you, you have to look deeper. Can you modify the code that acquires or assembles that string, and perhaps alter your approach so that the string never acquires the spaces in the first place?

Depending on how the original string comes into existence, there are many different ways to try to assemble such a string.

The naive answer is to use `StringBuilder`, however, depending on your constraints, that may not be appropriate. Every time you call `StringBuilder.Append()`, it performs a copy of the string data into its own internal buffers; and then when you finally call `StringBuilder.ToString()`, it performs another copy from its internal buffers into the final string object that it assembles to return to you.

Depending on the circumstance, a call to `string.Concat(string[])` may be efficient, if you have your string parts in the form of string objects.

...

There are other ways, however. Using unsafe/fixed statements, you can initialize your own strings, from scratch. This is exactly how string's own methods work, like `string.Join` or `string.Trim()`. Doing this yourself is possible, but requires that you very carefully handle strings, and is also technically against the language specification.

If you find yourself going down this path - initializing your own strings manually - I have a post that may provide some help:

[Is it possible to concatenate a list of strings using only a single allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217255/is-it-possible-to-concatenate-a-list-of-strings-using-only-a-single-allocation/32258224#32258224)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do it. The closest solution will be:

```
var myString = "  my string  ".Trim();
```